# Jquery and php, load images and use the src of each image

Tags: php, jquery, input, while-loop, image

I have a page that display a group of images with the src of each image, but I need to use the src valu of the images.
The images loads correctly but when I try to load into input text the src value of the selection image it not work:

```
    $("#recurs").click(function(){
    $("input[name=''valReturn]").val($("rec").val());
});
```

the php code:

```
$recu= $objRecur->show_rec_project($aux["IdProject"]);
    if(!empty($recu)){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recu)){
            echo'<img src="'.$row["srcrecursos"].'" id="recurs"/><br />';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No items found';
    }
```

And the input that need to load the src value:

```
<input type="text" id="valReturn" name="valReturn" width="25px"/> <br/>
```

The php code works but for to load the value into valReturn value not.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$("#recurs").click(function(){
    $("input[name=valReturn]").val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

or

```
$("#recurs").bind("click", function(){
    $("input[name=valReturn]").val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

In `val` use `$(this)` instead `$("#recurs")`

**UPDATED**

```
$(".recurs").click(function(){
    $("input[name=valReturn]").val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

or

```
$(".recurs").bind("click", function(){
    $("input[name=valReturn]").val($(this).attr('src'));
});

<img src="'.$row["srcrecursos"].'" class="recurs"/>
```

Comment: Try to create image element with class instead of id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
$("#recurs").click(function(){
    $("input[name=valReturn]").val($("#recurs").attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#recurs").click(function(){
            $("input[name='valReturn']").val($(this).attr('src'));
        }
    });
</script>
```